# Exception handler (empty text field)

Tags: javascript, exception, handler

I am writing a program that holds 4 data types in 4 Text Field boxes. The first box holds a name, the second an age, third email, and lastly a phone number. I want to add an exception handler that covers the empty text box. I am not sure how to write this part of the program. Can someone please help me? Here is what I have so far.

```
private void nextEntry() throws Exception
    {
        //Zero out all input fields
        cName.setText("");
        cAge.setText("");
        cEmail.setText("");
        cPhone.setText(""); 

    }

    private class submitButtonListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Write file to data file
            try {
                //Get
                String name = cName.getText();
                String age = cAge.getText();
                String email = cEmail.getText();
                String phone = cPhone.getText();

                Integer intAge = Integer.parseInt(age);

                //Validate Input                
                //If name is blank 
                if (name == "") {
                    throw InputMismatchException();
                }

                catch (InputMismatchException e){
                    //If name is blank
                    System.out.println("Please enter a name" + e.getMessage());
                }
                else if (age == "") {
                    //Age exists validation



                } else if (intAge > 120) {
                    //Age number validation


                } else if (email == "") {
                    //Email exists validation


                } else if (phone == "") {
                    //Phone exists validation


                } else {
                    //PASSED VALIDATION
                    fileWrite();
                    //Ready for next user input
                    nextEntry();
                }



            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```